# Error when restoring backup folder from Duplicity

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I performed a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 and there are certain directories I want to restore from my Deja Dup backup (only one complete backup performed). I chose to use duplicity, as I want to specify these directories only.

To see the correct paths for the directories I need, I did:

```
list-current-files <URL>
```

I tried to restore chosen directories to a new directory in my home directory using:

```
duplicity -t 3D --no-encryption --file-to-restore <path of backup directory> <URL>  </restore_path/>
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error '('Error creating directory </restore_path>', 7)' processing
```

I did:

```
duplicity collection-status <path to backup>
```

and received the following:

```
Last full backup date: <date>
Collection Status
-----------------
Connecting with backend: BackendWrapper
Archive dir: /home/karen/.cache/duplicity/9394baecea6181912d51fe8d3bff0034

Found 0 secondary backup chains.

Found primary backup chain with matching signature chain:
-------------------------
Chain start time: <date>
Chain end time: <date>
Number of contained backup sets: 1
Total number of contained volumes: 16661
 Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:
                Full         <date>             16661
-------------------------
No orphaned or incomplete backup sets found.
```

Please can you help with the "Error creating directory" message that I receive, as I don't know what it means.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How are you inputting your restore directory?

I believe I had the same error and solved it by placing a `/dir` at the end like so:

```
/media/USER/TARGET_DRIVE/dir
```

I found that answer in an old thread somewhere. Been too focused on restoring my own backup to make the bookmark, sorry.

A complete restore command should look like this:

```
sudo duplicity restore file:///media/USER/BACKUP_DEVICE/BACKUP_SOURCE /media/USER/TARGET_DEVICE/dir
```

As a disclaimer it's not working for me, but I'm quite certain the issue isn't with the above command but with a file in my backup.

Also: you may, or may not have to use sudo.